# When i try to install my certificate in keychain, the error says: Unable to import - Error Code 25294

Tags: ios, keychain, certificate

I am using the 10.9.5 version and ios 8. When i try to install my certificate i got through my developer account for push notification for my app in the keychain local items, its not importing. The error says: Unable to import the certificate and the error code is 25294

Comment: This is how I fixed it with the command line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485806/install-p12-or-cer-in-console-macos

Comment: Still relevant for macOS 12.2 in 2022. Got the same issue when installing Charles Proxy's root certs: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675290?login=true&page=1#703039022

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try adding the certificate to the "login" keychain.

Comment: Please do not delete this answer, as it answers the question and I could not find this solution elsewhere

Comment: yeah that was my problem, I was in the "iCloud" keychain. Login one worked.

Answer (score 14):

I worked around this error by adding the certificate to the login keychain by drag and drop.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This also seems to have worked for me, but it says the certificate is not trusted (unlike the one I'm replacing).

Answer (score 7):

Instead of double clicking the .cer file and importing in finder I just drag & dropped it into the Keychain app in the desired keychain, that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

The error code means ["No such keychain"](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-29/Keychain/SecKeychainAPI.h):

```
errSecNoSuchKeychain -25294 The specified keychain could not be found.
```

I'm not really sure on how to proceed, but maybe this information points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not sure about what you're question is asking, but I stumbled here while trying to solve the same error. The situation I had on my machine was I had a bunch of similarly named keychains in keychain access and the application would default to adding the .pem to a nonexistent keychain.

So I solved this by selecting the missing keychains one by one and deleting them all except my real System keychain, iCloud, and login. You might not have iCloud depending on your setup, version, and location.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error by deleting old certificates from Keychain, then try to install certificate by double click.

Comment: How is this different from the answer already provided in 2015?